# How to overwrite Code Climate test coverage report to the same commit

Tags: circleci, code-climate

I am using [cc-test-reporter](https://docs.codeclimate.com/v1.0/docs/circle-ci-test-coverage-example) to upload the test coverage result to `Code Climate` from `CircleCI`

But running the same build fails with the message:

```
Error: response from https://api.codeclimate.com/v1/test_reports.
HTTP 409: A test report for commit 
858d3fa0c92ec5a546bde3991f57523768dac0c2 already exists
```

How do I make it pass the CI scripts or overwrite it without any fails ?

Comment: Looks like the issue has been fixed by codeclimate now- https://github.com/codeclimate/test-reporter/issues/192